# Ignore pattern inside message with regex from rsyslog

Tags: regex, rsyslog

I'm trying to solve a regex problem with rsyslog but I've been got hard to get the desired output.
I've been developing on https://www.rsyslog.com/regex/

The logs have this form:

```
{"trace_indices":["psno_elastic"],"utc_timestamp":"2022-02-01T21:18:57.214+00:00","request_headers":"{Acess=Low 2j3k4uuuuuuuui=}","trace_id":null,"audit_category":"AUTHENTICATED","aud_reason":"Action: indices:data/write/index","@version":"1","ad_principal":null,"format_version":2,"remote_address":"10.135.99.176:52634","request_user":"superuser","audit_trace_source":"{\"Timestamp\" : \"1643749681989\",\"Index\" : \"hive_black_d\",\"Index_Class\" : \"hive_qxs_netfixa\",\"Shards\" : \"389\",\"MBytes\" : \"0.236956\"}","ad_date":"Tue Feb 01 21:10:57 WET 2022","audit_details":"indices:data/write/index","@timestamp":"2022-02-01T21:12:00.665Z","audit_request_type":"transport","request_class":"class org.elasticsearch.action.index.IndexRequest","trace_index_types":["default"],"trace_resolved_indices":["psno_elastic"]}
```

And I want to get this, eliminate just the extra next to Low:

```
{"trace_indices":["psno_elastic"],"utc_timestamp":"2022-02-01T21:18:57.214+00:00","request_headers":"{Acess=Low}","trace_id":null,"audit_category":"AUTHENTICATED","aud_reason":"Action: indices:data/write/index","@version":"1","ad_principal":null,"format_version":2,"remote_address":"10.135.99.176:52634","request_user":"superuser","audit_trace_source":"{\"Timestamp\" : \"1643749681989\",\"Index\" : \"hive_black_d\",\"Index_Class\" : \"hive_qxs_netfixa\",\"Shards\" : \"389\",\"MBytes\" : \"0.236956\"}","ad_date":"Tue Feb 01 21:10:57 WET 2022","audit_details":"indices:data/write/index","@timestamp":"2022-02-01T21:12:00.665Z","audit_request_type":"transport","request_class":"class org.elasticsearch.action.index.IndexRequest","trace_index_types":["default"],"trace_resolved_indices":["psno_elastic"]}
```

I tried to do following regex pattern:

```
"(.*Access=?)(?>=(Low 2j3k4uuuuuuuui=(.*)$))"
```

And the results were :

```
0: {"trace_indices":["psno_elastic"],"utc_timestamp":"2022-02-01T21:18:57.214+00:00","request_headers":"{Access=Low 2j3k4uuuuuuuui=}","trace_id":null,"audit_category":"AUTHENTICATED","aud_reason":"Action: indices:data/write/index","@version":"1","ad_principal":null,"format_version":2,"remote_address":"10.135.99.176:52634","request_user":"superuser","audit_trace_source":"{\"Timestamp\" : \"1643749681989\",\"Index\" : \"hive_black_d\",\"Index_Class\" : \"hive_qxs_netfixa\",\"Shards\" : \"389\",\"MBytes\" : \"0.236956\"}","ad_date":"Tue Feb 01 21:10:57 WET 2022","audit_details":"indices:data/write/index","@timestamp":"2022-02-01T21:12:00.665Z","audit_request_type":"transport","request_class":"class org.elasticsearch.action.index.IndexRequest","trace_index_types":["default"],"trace_resolved_indices":["psno_elastic"]}
1: {"trace_indices":["psno_elastic"],"utc_timestamp":"2022-02-01T21:18:57.214+00:00","request_headers":"{Access
2: Low 2j3k4uuuuuuuui=}","trace_id":null,"audit_category":"AUTHENTICATED","aud_reason":"Action: indices:data/write/index","@version":"1","ad_principal":null,"format_version":2,"remote_address":"10.135.99.176:52634","request_user":"superuser","audit_trace_source":"{\"Timestamp\" : \"1643749681989\",\"Index\" : \"hive_black_d\",\"Index_Class\" : \"hive_qxs_netfixa\",\"Shards\" : \"389\",\"MBytes\" : \"0.236956\"}","ad_date":"Tue Feb 01 21:10:57 WET 2022","audit_details":"indices:data/write/index","@timestamp":"2022-02-01T21:12:00.665Z","audit_request_type":"transport","request_class":"class org.elasticsearch.action.index.IndexRequest","trace_index_types":["default"],"trace_resolved_indices":["psno_elastic"]}
3: }","trace_id":null,"audit_category":"AUTHENTICATED","aud_reason":"Action: indices:data/write/index","@version":"1","ad_principal":null,"format_version":2,"remote_address":"10.135.99.176:52634","request_user":"superuser","audit_trace_source":"{\"Timestamp\" : \"1643749681989\",\"Index\" : \"hive_black_d\",\"Index_Class\" : \"hive_qxs_netfixa\",\"Shards\" : \"389\",\"MBytes\" : \"0.236956\"}","ad_date":"Tue Feb 01 21:10:57 WET 2022","audit_details":"indices:data/write/index","@timestamp":"2022-02-01T21:12:00.665Z","audit_request_type":"transport","request_class":"class org.elasticsearch.action.index.IndexRequest","trace_index_types":["default"],"trace_resolved_indices":["psno_elastic"]}
```

The numbers (0,1,2,3) are the Submatch to Use.
I don't know what's the right regex expression to use to match the desired output...

Thank You.

Comment: I did not understand how  https://www.rsyslog.com/regex/ works, but to replace this substring with sed you shoud use `sed -E 's/(.*\{Acess=Low)[^}]*(\}.*)/\1\2/'` . Try to use regex `(.*\{Acess=Low)[^}]*(\}.*)` and use submatches 1 and 2. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I used regex101.com in mode PCRE2 & substitution.
The regex string

```
/^([\w\W]*)2j3k4uuuuuuuui=([\w\W]*)$/gm
```

with the source string

```
":"Action: indices:data/write/index","@version":"1","ad_principal":null,"format_version":2,"remote_address":"10.135.99.176:52634","request_user":"superuser","audit_trace_source":"{\"Timestamp\" : \"1643749681989\",\"Index\" : \"hive_black_d\",\"Index_Class\" : \"hive_qxs_netfixa\",\"Shards\" : \"389\",\"MBytes\" : \"0.236956\"}","ad_date":"Tue Feb 01 21:10:57 WET 2022","audit_details":"indices:data/write/index","@timestamp":"2022-02-01T21:12:00.665Z","audit_request_type":"transport","request_class":"class org.elasticsearch.action.index.IndexRequest","trace_index_types":["default"],"trace_resolved_indices":["psno_elastic"]}
```

and the substitution `$1$2`gave the desired result:

```
{"trace_indices":["psno_elastic"],"utc_timestamp":"2022-02-01T21:18:57.214+00:00","request_headers":"{Acess=Low }","trace_id":null,"audit_category":"AUTHENTICATED","aud_reason":"Action: indices:data/write/index","@version":"1","ad_principal":null,"format_version":2,"remote_address":"10.135.99.176:52634","request_user":"superuser","audit_trace_source":"{\"Timestamp\" : \"1643749681989\",\"Index\" : \"hive_black_d\",\"Index_Class\" : \"hive_qxs_netfixa\",\"Shards\" : \"389\",\"MBytes\" : \"0.236956\"}","ad_date":"Tue Feb 01 21:10:57 WET 2022","audit_details":"indices:data/write/index","@timestamp":"2022-02-01T21:12:00.665Z","audit_request_type":"transport","request_class":"class org.elasticsearch.action.index.IndexRequest","trace_index_types":["default"],"trace_resolved_indices":["psno_elastic"]}
```